# How to add fingerprint scanner in flutter app

Tags: flutter, fingerprint

I am trying to add fingerprint authentication in my screen app by using `local_auth` package in flutter.. but my device doesn't support fingerprint... my android version is 7.1.1 ... is there a way to add authentication using fingerprint when device doesn't support?.. or is there a package in flutter to add fingerprint scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because your device will not be able to read your biometrics. No lib can help you with that.